# Process ID will not allow me to use a variable as its value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to assign a variable to the **process.id(*value*)** but visual basic says I can't, the code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
Dim a As New Process
Dim id As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    a.Id(id)
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("x")
End Sub
End Class
```

The **a.Id(id)** is the problem, the editor says it is a syntax error.
What the editor says: Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

Comment: You can say `id = a.Id` (read from the "id" property).  But your syntax (treating "id" like a method call) is just wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you think you want to set the process id?

Comment: I am trying to let the user select a program to input text into, and then the program enters text the user wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Process.Id` isn't a function, [it's a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id.aspx).  And it's not settable anyway.

You can read it as `a.Id` and use it as such, but you can't modify it.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
a.Id = id
```

That assumes the property is writable, which it probably isn't.

Comment: Member property, I think. I strongly suspected it was read-only.

Comment: In other words, you'd probably just be replacing a compile-time error with a runtime exception :)

Comment: @paulsm4: Nah, it'll still be compile-time.  There's no setter for the `Id` property so trying to set it wouldn't compile.  Either way, it's entirely unclear why the OP thinks this should even be done.